# JavaライブラリでAutowiredする方法

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, spring

Javaでいろいろな便利クラスが同梱されたライブラリ（mainメソッドが無いjar）を作成しています。
ライブラリプロジェクトにおいて、SpringフレームワークのAutowiredアノテーションは利用可能でしょうか。

なお、当該ライブラリを利用する側のアプリケーションではSpringフレームワークを利用していません。

開発環境：Eclipse, Windows
開発言語：Java

利用不可である場合、理由についてご教示頂けると大変助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Autowiredアノテーションは利用可能でしょうか。

利用可能です。

利用するアプリケーション ←→ 作成しているライブラリ

で、相互参照(相互依存)しているように思われているのかもしれませんが、そうではなく利用するアプリケーションも作成しているライブラリも、Springフレームワークを参照するように構成すればいいだけです。

利用するアプリケーション → 作成しているライブラリ
　　　　　　　　　↓　　　　　↓
　　　　　　　Springフレームワーク

※「→」は参照関係を表しています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。利用するアプリケーションは昔に作られた既存アプリで、Strutsか何かで作られています。Spring フレームワークを使っていないのです。要するに突然、当該ライブラリの、とあるメソッドがリフレクションか何かでよばれて、その瞬間にSpring フレームワークに必要な初期化が行われる様にするにはどうすればよいかという質問なのです…

Comment: 「Springフレームワークを利用していません。」と書いてあったんですね。「利用しています」と読み間違えました...

Comment: そうなのですね！現在はうまく設定できていないだけかもしれません。もう少し調査してみます。なにか、参考情報やこの様なケースの検索キーワードなどご教示頂けると大変助かります…

Comment: いずれにしても利用可能です。利用するアプリケーション → 作成しているライブラリ → Springフレームワーク という依存関係で構成すれば、いいと思いますが、何かうまくいかないことがあったら、それをこのサイトで質問して下さい。